# Jasper reports from .Net framework

Tags: .net, jasper-reports

Is there any way of generating jasper report from a .Net 3.5 application ??

Please let me know any chances

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the REST Based API for Jasper reports which is language independent.
http://community.jaspersoft.com/wiki/getting-started-rest-web-service-api

Apart from that you have [JNI4NET](http://jni4net.sourceforge.net/) which is a bridge between .net and java applications. 
Use the generateProxies tool that comes with the package to generate a proxy for the JAVA class you directly reference from within .NET.

But the REST Api is the recommended method... as it is directly supported by Jaspersoft.

Comment: In this case we have to use *JR Server*

Comment: Jaspersoft Report Server Community is licensed under AGPL License - https://community.jaspersoft.com/project/jasperreports-server/releases , may not be suitable for distribution or SaaS based commercial offering.

Comment: @MaulikModi Not sure what is the confusion regarding it. Basically you can't edit their code and distribute or use, until and unless you do that you are free to use even commercially. Please read https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/107883/agpl-what-you-can-do-and-what-you-cant

Comment: Refer slide #20 on https://www.slideshare.net/jaspersoft/jaspersoft-community-or-commercialwhich-jaspersoft-edition-is-right-for-you

Comment: @MaulikModi


#1. Does this apply if we don't update/modify Jasper source code?

#2. Does this apply if we don't link it but used as a seperate report server used over the REST API?